# Not able to delete container disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, big-sur

[image]

I wish to delete this container disk 1 and disk utility is not allowing me to. And if I restart my mac it automatoically boots to container disk 1. so I should always boot from the other disk manually. Can some please help me how to do it? Thank You in advance.

Comment: You should use Recovery Mode, which will let you delete any of your disks. Recovery mode can be accessed by holding ⌘+R immediately after pressing the power button to turn on your computer.

Comment: Try holding down the control key while selecting the desired macOS from Mac Startup Manager. Also, can you include the output from the command `diskutil list`? Also, which version of macOS are you using?